# JS file in script tag's src attribute downloaded but not executed(from ajax call)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am invoking an ajax call from jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'edit.htm',
  success: function(data){
    container.html(data);
  },
});
```

The data recevied from the ajax call contains script tags that reference other JS files, for ex: angularjs. Wehn I look at firebug I see that the JS files are downloaded but they do not appear in the Script tab one could debug it.

The JS files are downloaded but not executed.

How do I get around this?

The above ajax call and the container element are present in a html file called info.htm.

And edit.htm(the data fetched from the ajax call) has script tags and other html data.

Thanks.
P.S: If it helps: I can see the JS files being downloaded in the firebug 'Console' tab, however, I cant see them listed in the firebug 'Script' tab.

Comment: Where should they be executed? What is triggering them?

Comment: Where is "container" defined? if you put container.html("###"); does it work?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment The above ajax snippet is located in a file called info.htm. The ajax call is executed on click of a hyperlink in info.htm. As you see the url is edit.htm. edit.htm has these script tags that contain JS files in the src attribute.

Comment: @Diodeus container is a variable defined in the same html file as the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `jQuery.getScript("url")` for more details refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)
It makes ajax call implicitly.

or try something like :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'edit.htm',
  success: function(data){
    $(data).appendTo(container);
  },
});
```

Comment: The url has more than just script tags it has html data as well.

Comment: I cant do that. As I have in my ajax snippet, I have to append the data to the 'container' element. And the data returned from the ajax call is not just a script tag it has html content along with script tag, it is a partial html file.

Comment: I could actually use the above Jquery function in edit.htm itself but the problem is the script tag has a custom attribute like this:               <script src="angular-0.9.19.js" ng:autobind></script>

Comment: @ChrisOdney append, or replace? Your OP implies the latter, but your comment just now says "append".

Comment: Sorry ...it is Replace not append.

Comment: Though it is not an exact answer, jQuery.getScript("url") helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had once a problem with CSS - it had incorrect `Content-Type` header and was not interpreted by the browser. Can that be the problem? Does your server return `text/javascript` for the requested script?

Comment: One note - the page `edit.htm` is probably full HTML page enclosed with `<html>` tags. Maybe the browser is not including the loaded script in the main page because of that. Try to return just the `<script>` tag to see if that is the case.

Comment: No, it does not have the html tag it has a div followed by script tags

Comment: I assume everything works if you include exactly the same content in the main page (not using AJAX). Correct?

Answer (score -3):

May be your requirement is kind of odd because server doesn't return client code.

Best practice is load js file at the start, and you can call required method after completion of ajax script.

However, eval may not be a good practise but this is one solution.
To execute javascript code which is in variable, you need to use eval method.

Please take a look at this reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

hope this helps.

Comment: Must resist... urge to downvote... for suggesting eval... Oh god, to make it worse you just linked to W3Fools.

Comment: Furthermore... whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Didn't resist urge. This is not a helpful answer. It doesn't describe *how* to use eval to solve the problem, *why* it's necessary (if it is at all), or really anything at all.